# Replace unknown number of whitespace with zeros [Regex/Java]

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text:

```
Dorothy 123456789  0        98765Fashion
```

I need to replace the space between **0** and **98765** with the *same amount of 0s* so it looks like:

```
Dorothy 123456789  0000098765Fashion
```

There is a catch:

- The exact number of whitespace between 0 and 98765 is unknown. There could be none, there could be many.
- The beginning 0 is a constant but the numbers in 98765 are also changing.

What I have so far only replaces the space between 0 and 98765 with just one single 0 but it doesnt match all the rest of the whitespace with zeros:

```
regexExpression = "(.{7}).(\\d{9})(..)0(\\s+)(\\d+)(.{7})";
replacement = "$1$2$300$5$6";
newString = oldString.replaceAll(regexExpression, replacement);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `\G` based regex here:

```
(?<=0|\G)\h(?=\h*\d)
```

and replace it with:

```
0
```

In Java code:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=0|\\G)\\h(?=\\h*\\d)", "0");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XKm9br/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match
- `(?<=0|\G)`: Make sure we have a zero or end of previous match at previous position
- `\h`: Match a horizontal whitespace
- `(?=\h*\d)`: Make sure we have 0 or more spaces followed by a digit ahead

Comment: Thank you so, so much - exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

### Java 9+

If you are using [**Java 9+**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) you can use [`Matcher::replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-) like so :

```
newString = Pattern.compile("0(\\s*)\\d+")
        .matcher(oldString)
        .replaceAll(g -> g.group(0).replace(" ", "0"));
```

Where `g.group(0)` will catch all the spaces between 0 and a number, then you can just replace each space in this group with 0. (simple and easy).

---

**Outputs**

```
Dorothy 123456789  00000000098765Fashion
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is coming in as a String I'd try the following:

`

```
String a = "Dorothy 123456789  0        98765Fashion";

char[] chars = a.toCharArray();

for(int i =0; i<chars.length;i++){

   if(chars[i]==0&&chars[i+1]==' '){
      chars[i+1]=0;
   }

}
```

`